# Why does English primarily use the Greek names for diseases?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, etymology

In Dutch, my native language, most diseases go by normal Dutch names (*longontsteking* for pneumonia, *buikgriep* for gastroenteritis, *hersenvliesontsteking* for meningitis, etc.), whereas in English the Greek names seem to be the default choice.

Is there any reason for this seemingly lack of anglicisation?

Comment: Is there any reason for the Dutchicisation of them in Dutch? The English way may be less intuitive to learn for native speakers, but they do mean that in a great many cases, you don’t need two completely separate systems of naming to reconcile doctorspeak and normalspeak.

Comment: Good question. I don't know. I tried looking it up in etymological dictionaries, but as those words are simply translated from Greek there doesn't seem to be a concise history.

Comment: In the past, the learned professions such as medicine used Latin (and presumably also knew Greek). Many diseases no doubt had English common names (such as 'consumption' for tuberculosis, 'bloody flux' for dysentery), but it's the learned names that have always been used by doctors for the sake of accuracy. I suppose it's similar to botanists using Latin names for plants rather than the common names which may be confusing and inaccurate.

Comment: Are the Dutch names used by medical professionals or is it just that the general populace hasn't picked up the use of the scientific names from the medical profession? If it's the latter I suspect that the English, having a tradition of regarding French and other foreign words as being 'posher' or 'more correct' than Anglo-Saxon derived words, would have been more willing to adopt them, particularly in middle class society.

Comment: In most cases, the medical professionals use the Dutch names in their communication with their patients. They tend to use the Greek terms in their mutual communication.

Comment: 'Why' questions are difficult. I don't doubt the phenomenon (I've seen it in German). But 'why' is especially difficult here because it seems to require linguistic knowledge and thorough sociological knowledge of healthcare in both English speaking and Dutch speaking countries. So we can only speculate as to why. This might for once be better asked as http://history.stackexchange.com

Comment: I would venture it's a holdover from the towering reputation of Galen throughout the Middle Ages and well into the Renaissance. Before my first trip to Greece, friends worried that communicating with physicians there would be a problem; I replied that physicians speak Greek here in America, too; over there they just pronounce it better!

Comment: @KateBunting: 6 upvotes already for a comment. That should be an answer!  If you leave a comment @ fabby, I'll come back and upvote! **:-)**

Comment: I think the use of Greek and Latin names is a relatively recent style. If you watch period TV shows or movies about doctors in the 19th century, they often used common names. I suspect it coincides with increased formalization of the medical education process.

Comment: Any answer will need to address (and possibly substantiate) the difference in usage between English and Dutch.

Comment: Because Hippocrates was Greek.

Comment: Adding to the comment of @Brian Donovan, [A Dictionary of Medical Terms in Galen](http://www.brill.com/dictionary-medical-terms-galen) lists 3,000 medical terms used by Galen with 119,000 citations -- possibly more than you want to know.

Comment: My guess, and it is only a guess: education in England at the upper levels of society stressed Greek and Latin.  No upper class twit could emerge from his public (i.e. private) school without having Greek and Latin beaten into him, some of which he actually retained.    Doctors aspired to be in the upper levels of society, ergo they used Greek and Latin words to signify that they were.  Did 19th century education in the Netherlands stress Greek and Latin?

Comment: ab2 - Latin was used all over Europe as a means of communication between educated men of different mother tongues, for many centuries.

Answer (score 1):

Since your question is about English, I can say that our active language uses words that change meaning over time, but inactive ones like Greek and Latin do not. I learned in Anatomy class that doctors the world over can communicate accurately by using standardized names from the inactive languages.

*Wicked*, once evil, is now fashionable. 
Similarly, *redundant* is bad in English, poetic in Biblical Hebrew, and well-advised in computer hardware.